# Sort pandas csv list with string date

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have read a couple of similar post regarding the issue before, but none of the solutions worked for me. so I got the followed csv :

```
    Score    date       term
0      72   3 Feb ·      1
1      47   1 Feb ·      1
2     119   6 Feb ·      1
8     101   7 hrs ·      1
9     536  11 min ·      1
10     53   2 hrs ·      1
11     20  11 Feb ·      3
3      15   1 hrs ·      2
4      33   7 Feb ·      1
5     153   4 Feb ·      3
6      34   3 min ·      2
7      26   3 Feb ·      3
```

I want to sort the csv by date. What's the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: what will happen to 11 min and 2 hrs ? also are all the years the same?

Comment: Years is all the same. the date is when something happened, something like "happened before"

Comment: My answer was unaccepted, there is some problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can create 2 helper columns - one for datetimes created by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and second for timedeltas created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), only necessary format `HH:MM:SS`, so added [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by regexes, so last is possible sorting by 2 columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %b', errors='coerce')
times = df['date'].replace({'(\d+)\s+min': '00:\\1:00',
                             '\s+hrs': ':00:00'}, regex=True)
df['times'] = pd.to_timedelta(times, errors='coerce')

df = df.sort_values(['times','date1'])
print (df)

    Score    date  term      date1    times
6      34   3 min     2        NaT 00:03:00
9     536  11 min     1        NaT 00:11:00
3      15   1 hrs     2        NaT 01:00:00
10     53   2 hrs     1        NaT 02:00:00
8     101   7 hrs     1        NaT 07:00:00
1      47   1 Feb     1 1900-02-01      NaT
0      72   3 Feb     1 1900-02-03      NaT
7      26   3 Feb     3 1900-02-03      NaT
5     153   4 Feb     3 1900-02-04      NaT
2     119   6 Feb     1 1900-02-06      NaT
4      33   7 Feb     1 1900-02-07      NaT
11     20  11 Feb     3 1900-02-11      NaT
```

Comment: Hey, @jezrael , thanks for your answer ! I just tried it, it was working very well for sorting the minutes from hours and so on.. But for some reason, it didn't sorted the days well. here i got an screenshot of  the problem : https://prnt.sc/r2p0d2 . I got to say, that i tried it on other files, with other times, but the concept is the same. didn't got any minutes in the test file, can that cause the problem ?

Comment: @AlexKalaidjiev - I think there should be some whitespaces in data like `'1 Feb '` ? If yes, then use `df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.strip(), format='%d %b', errors='coerce')`

Comment: you was right, there was an "whitespace". fixed it with:
```nf=len(df)
for i in range(nf):
    asd = df.at[i,"date"]
    asd = asd.split()
    new = asd[0] + " " + asd[1]
    df.at[i,"date"] = new
```
Thank you very much for your time !